# How to evaluate conditions after each other in Pandas .loc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a Pandas DataFrame where column `B` contains mixed types

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   False
1   2   abc False
2   3   2   False
3   4   3   False
4   5   b   False
```

I want to modify column `C` to be True when the value in column `B` is of type `int` and also has a value greater than or equal to 3. So in this example `df['B'][3]` should match this condition

I tried to do this:

```
df.loc[(df['B'].astype(str).str.isdigit()) & (df['B'] >= 3)] = True
```

However I get the following error because of the `str` values inside column `B`:

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

If I'm able to only test the second condition on the subset provided after the first condition this would solve my problem I think. What can I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way without the use of apply would be to use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` which will change the `str` type to `NaN`, without changing the type of column B:

```
df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df.B, 'coerce') >= 3

>>> print(df) 

   A    B      C
0  1    1  False
1  2  abc  False
2  3    2  False
3  4    3   True
4  5    b  False
```

Comment: nice! simpler is `df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df.B, 'coerce') >= 3`

Answer (score 3):

One solution could be:

```
df["B"].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit() and int(x) >= 3)
```

If x is not a digit, then the evaluation will stop and won't try to parse `x` to `int` - which throws a `ValueError` if the argument is not parseable into an `int`.

Comment: this is a good answer

Comment: Need to cast the ints to a string to use isdigit: `df["B"].apply(lambda x: str(x).isdigit() and x >= 3)`

Comment: @Paul Yes - that is correct - assumed all the elements where strings (I loaded a dataframe I had in memory). Let me amend that! Liked the comment

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways around this (e.g. use a custom (lambda) function with `df.apply`, use `df.replace()` first), but I think the easiest way might be just to use an intermediate column.
First, create a new column that does the first check, then do the second check on this new column.

Answer (score 1):

This works (although nikeros' answer is more elegant).

```
def check_maybe_int(n):
    return int(n) >= 3 if n.isdigit() else False

df.B.apply(check_maybe_int)
```

But the real answer is, don't do this! Mixed columns prevent a lot of Pandas' optimisations. `apply` is not vectorised, so it's a lot slower than vector int comparison should be.

Comment: Paul made my a fair comment to my post. `check_maybe_int` will throw an error as well if called with an `int` - like check_maybe_int(4)

Comment: true, and solution would be the same change: `if str(n).isdigit()`. But I'd rather write a simpler answer than one which covers all edge cases, since OP hasn't specified

Answer (score 0):

you can use `apply(type)` as picture illustrate

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4,1, 2],'col3': [1, 2,1, 2],'col4': [1, 'e',True, 2.345]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
a = df.col4.apply(type)
b = [ i==str for i in a  ]
df['col5'] = b
```